# DOM Element Not Rendering on Page Until After JS Transition Completion

Tags: javascript, html, css, rendering, element

The title says it all.  To see the issue, copy this code to the following online compiler: https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_compiler

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<style>
        /*MAIN*/

        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            user-select: none;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        body {
            background-color: #FF0000;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }


        /*ELEMENTS*/

        div {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            float: left;
            margin-left: 0vw;
        }

        h1 {
            font-family: verdana;
            font-size: 5vh;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        h1.white {
            color: #F4F4F4;
        }

</style>

<body>
    
    <div id = "main" style = "width: auto; margin-left: 0vw;">
        
        <div id = "home" class = "container" style = 'background-color: #000000;'>
            
            <h1 class = "white">click arrow to see how the next page doesn't appear until after the transition is complete</h1>
                            
            <!--ARROW BUTTON-->
            <p id = 'arrowButton' style = 'color: #FFFFFF; position: absolute; height: 10vh; width: auto; margin: 45vh 0 0 75vw; font-size: 3vh;' onMouseDown = 'NextButtonClick();'>--></p>
            
        </div>
        
        <div id = "welcome" class = "container" style = 'background-color: #FFFFFF;'>
                
            <h1 style = 'margin: 47.5vh 0 0 50vw'>welcome to my portfolio</h1>
            
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
    <script>
        var mainDiv, welcomeDiv;
            var transitionSeconds = 0.5;
            var isTransitioning = false;
            
            function NextButtonClick() {
                if(!isTransitioning) {
                    isTransitioning = true;
                    
                    i = 0;
                    thisInterval = setInterval(function() {
                        mainDiv.style.marginLeft = (100 / i) - 101 + "vw";
                        
                        i++;
                        if(i == 100) {
                            clearInterval(thisInterval);
                            mainDiv.style.marginLeft = "-100vw";
                            isTransitioning = false;
                        }
                    }, transitionSeconds);
                }
            }
            
            window.onload = function() {
                mainDiv = document.getElementById("main");
                welcomeDiv = document.getElementById("welcome");
                
                var arrowButton = document.getElementById("arrowButton");
                var arrowButtonX, arrowButtonY;
                var arrowButtonGlowDistance = 100;
                
                arrowButtonX = arrowButton.getBoundingClientRect().left + arrowButton.getBoundingClientRect().width/2;//center
                arrowButtonY = arrowButton.getBoundingClientRect().top + arrowButton.getBoundingClientRect().height/2;//center
                
                document.onmousemove = function(e) {
                    x = e.clientX; y = e.clientY;
                };
            };
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

The background is red on purpose so that you can see how, even though the "welcome" div should be rendered over top the background, it is not being rendered until the very last second after the transition is completed and 100% of the element is on the screen.

I am stumped, and I'm not sure why this is since HTML usually doesn't seem to behave this way.  Even when I highlight the element in Inspect Element, the Inspector doesn't show me where the element is on the screen until the final moment when it is rendered.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I look forward to hearing your feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your DIVs are placed under each other and while one is moving horizontally, the next div is still underneath of it until first one is completely out of the way (just like Jenga game in reverse).
To solve this, you can try add `display: flex`, to place them horizontally instead:

```js
var mainDiv, welcomeDiv;
var transitionSeconds = 0.5;
var isTransitioning = false;

function NextButtonClick() {
  if (!isTransitioning) {
    isTransitioning = true;

    i = 0;
    thisInterval = setInterval(function() {
      mainDiv.style.marginLeft = (100 / i) - 101 + "vw";

      i++;
      if (i == 100) {
        clearInterval(thisInterval);
        mainDiv.style.marginLeft = "-100vw";
        isTransitioning = false;
      }
    }, transitionSeconds);
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  mainDiv = document.getElementById("main");
  welcomeDiv = document.getElementById("welcome");

  var arrowButton = document.getElementById("arrowButton");
  var arrowButtonX, arrowButtonY;
  var arrowButtonGlowDistance = 100;

  arrowButtonX = arrowButton.getBoundingClientRect().left + arrowButton.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2; //center
  arrowButtonY = arrowButton.getBoundingClientRect().top + arrowButton.getBoundingClientRect().height / 2; //center

  document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    x = e.clientX;
    y = e.clientY;
  };
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  user-select: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/*ELEMENTS*/

div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0vw;
  display: flex; /* added */ 
}

h1 {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 5vh;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h1.white {
  color: #F4F4F4;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" style="width: auto; margin-left: 0vw;">

  <div id="home" class="container" style='background-color: #000000;'>

    <h1 class="white">click arrow to see how the next page doesn't appear until after the transition is complete</h1>

    <!--ARROW BUTTON-->
    <p id='arrowButton' style='color: #FFFFFF; position: absolute; height: 10vh; width: auto; margin: 45vh 0 0 75vw; font-size: 3vh;' onMouseDown='NextButtonClick();'>--></p>

  </div>

  <div id="welcome" class="container" style='background-color: #FFFFFF;'>

    <h1 style='margin: 47.5vh 0 0 50vw'>welcome to my portfolio</h1>

  </div>

</div>
```